How to work with a type from a Rust made library in Python
I am making a Rust based library for Python which implements different cryptographic protocols, and I'm having trouble working with EphemeralSecret, as I keep getting the error log:
"no method named to_bytes found for struct EphemeralSecret in the current scope
method not found in EphemeralSecret"

This is being used to create a Rust lib to use it in Python so I can implement different cryptographic protocols and I need to work with the created keys in my Python side of things. I understand I maybe shouldn´t need to have a privateKey serialized for security reasons, but this is my case, so how do I "pass" it? Or should I maybe convert it in another way to work with it and be able to pass it around?
I also have the trouble when converting it "back" from python to rust as there is no conversion back to it from bytes.
The trouble is in the following section:
// Elliptic Curve Diffie-Hellman
#[pyfunction]
fn generate_ecdh_key() -> PyResult<(Vec<u8>, Vec<u8>)> {
    let private_key = EphemeralSecret::random_from_rng(OsRng);
    let public_key = PublicKey::from(&private_key);
    
    Ok((private_key.to_bytes().to_vec(), public_key.as_bytes().to_vec()))
}

#[pyfunction]
fn derive_ecdh_shared_key(private_key_bytes: Vec<u8>, server_public_key_bytes: Vec<u8>) -> PyResult<Vec<u8>> {
    let private_key = EphemeralSecret::from(private_key_bytes.as_slice().try_into().unwrap());
    let server_public_key = PublicKey::from(server_public_key_bytes.as_slice().try_into().unwrap());

    let shared_secret = private_key.diffie_hellman(&server_public_key);
    Ok(shared_secret.as_bytes().to_vec())
}

It is part of the complete code:
use pyo3::prelude::*;
use pyo3::wrap_pyfunction;
use x25519_dalek::{EphemeralSecret, PublicKey};
use rand::Rng;
use rand::rngs::OsRng;
use num_bigint::{BigUint, RandBigInt};
use rsa::{RsaPrivateKey, RsaPublicKey, Pkcs1v15Encrypt};
use rsa::pkcs1::{DecodeRsaPrivateKey, DecodeRsaPublicKey, EncodeRsaPrivateKey, EncodeRsaPublicKey};
use rsa::pkcs8::LineEnding;

// Diffie-Hellman
#[pyfunction]
fn generate_dh_key(p: &str, g: &str) -> PyResult<(String, String)> {
    let p = BigUint::parse_bytes(p.as_bytes(), 10).ok_or_else(|| pyo3::exceptions::PyValueError::new_err("Invalid p"))?;
    let g = BigUint::parse_bytes(g.as_bytes(), 10).ok_or_else(|| pyo3::exceptions::PyValueError::new_err("Invalid g"))?;
    
    let mut rng = OsRng;
    let private_key = rng.gen_biguint_below(&p);
    let public_key = g.modpow(&private_key, &p);

    Ok((private_key.to_str_radix(10), public_key.to_str_radix(10)))
}

#[pyfunction]
fn derive_dh_shared_key(private_key: &str, server_public_key: &str, p: &str) -> PyResult<String> {
    let p = BigUint::parse_bytes(p.as_bytes(), 10).ok_or_else(|| pyo3::exceptions::PyValueError::new_err("Invalid p"))?;
    let private_key = BigUint::parse_bytes(private_key.as_bytes(), 10).ok_or_else(|| pyo3::exceptions::PyValueError::new_err("Invalid private_key"))?;
    let server_public_key = BigUint::parse_bytes(server_public_key.as_bytes(), 10).ok_or_else(|| pyo3::exceptions::PyValueError::new_err("Invalid server_public_key"))?;

    let shared_secret = server_public_key.modpow(&private_key, &p);
    Ok(shared_secret.to_str_radix(10))
}

// Elliptic Curve Diffie-Hellman
#[pyfunction]
fn generate_ecdh_key() -> PyResult<(Vec<u8>, Vec<u8>)> {
    let private_key = EphemeralSecret::random_from_rng(OsRng);
    let public_key = PublicKey::from(&private_key);
    
    Ok((private_key.to_bytes().to_vec(), public_key.as_bytes().to_vec()))
}

#[pyfunction]
fn derive_ecdh_shared_key(private_key_bytes: Vec<u8>, server_public_key_bytes: Vec<u8>) -> PyResult<Vec<u8>> {
    let private_key = EphemeralSecret::from(private_key_bytes.as_slice().try_into().unwrap());
    let server_public_key = PublicKey::from(server_public_key_bytes.as_slice().try_into().unwrap());

    let shared_secret = private_key.diffie_hellman(&server_public_key);
    Ok(shared_secret.as_bytes().to_vec())
}

// RSA Functions
#[pyfunction]
fn generate_rsa_key() -> (String, String) {
    let mut rng = OsRng;
    let bits = 2048;

    let private_key = RsaPrivateKey::new(&mut rng, bits).unwrap();
    let public_key = RsaPublicKey::from(&private_key);

    let private_pem = private_key.to_pkcs1_pem(LineEnding::LF).unwrap();
    let public_pem = public_key.to_pkcs1_pem(LineEnding::LF).unwrap();

    (private_pem.to_string(), public_pem)
}

#[pyfunction]
fn rsa_encrypt(public_key_pem: &str, message: &str) -> Vec<u8> {
    let public_key = RsaPublicKey::from_pkcs1_pem(public_key_pem).unwrap();
    let mut rng = OsRng;
    public_key.encrypt(&mut rng, Pkcs1v15Encrypt, message.as_bytes()).unwrap()
}

#[pyfunction]
fn rsa_decrypt(private_key_pem: &str, encrypted_data: Vec<u8>) -> String {
    let private_key = RsaPrivateKey::from_pkcs1_pem(private_key_pem).unwrap();
    let decrypted_data = private_key.decrypt(Pkcs1v15Encrypt, &encrypted_data).unwrap();
    String::from_utf8(decrypted_data).unwrap()
}

// Swoosh NIKE key generation and exchange
#[pyfunction]
fn swoosh_generate_keys(parameters: (usize, usize, usize)) -> PyResult<(Vec<i8>, Vec<i8>)> {
    let (q, _d, n) = parameters;
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
    let a: Vec<i8> = (0..n * n).map(|_| rng.gen_range(0..q) as i8).collect();
    let s: Vec<i8> = (0..n).map(|_| rng.gen_range(-1..=1)).collect();
    let e: Vec<i8> = (0..n).map(|_| rng.gen_range(-1..=1)).collect();
    let public_key: Vec<i8> = a.chunks(n).zip(&s).map(|(row, &s)| (row.iter().sum::<i8>() + e[s as usize]) % q as i8).collect();
    Ok((s, public_key))
}

#[pyfunction]
fn swoosh_derive_shared_key(private_key: Vec<i8>, public_key: Vec<i8>, q: usize) -> PyResult<Vec<i8>> {
    let shared_key: Vec<i8> = private_key.iter().zip(&public_key).map(|(&s, &p)| (s * p) % q as i8).collect();
    Ok(shared_key)
}

#[pymodule]
fn shadowCrypt(m: &Bound<'_, PyModule>) -> PyResult<()> {
    m.add_function(wrap_pyfunction!(generate_dh_key, m)?)?;
    m.add_function(wrap_pyfunction!(derive_dh_shared_key, m)?)?;
    m.add_function(wrap_pyfunction!(generate_ecdh_key, m)?)?;
    m.add_function(wrap_pyfunction!(derive_ecdh_shared_key, m)?)?;
    m.add_function(wrap_pyfunction!(generate_rsa_key, m)?)?;
    m.add_function(wrap_pyfunction!(rsa_encrypt, m)?)?;
    m.add_function(wrap_pyfunction!(rsa_decrypt, m)?)?;
    m.add_function(wrap_pyfunction!(swoosh_generate_keys, m)?)?;
    m.add_function(wrap_pyfunction!(swoosh_derive_shared_key, m)?)?;
    Ok(())
}



How did you get to a conclusion that it has a method to_bytes()?

It seems the crate is designed to prevent what you're trying (rightfully). It looks impossible to serialize the key. If you need to pass it to Python, you can wrap it in a #[pyclass].

EphemeralSecret does not have a to_bytes method as Ephemeral Secrets cannot be serialized to Vec as mentioned in the docs.

This type is identical to the StaticSecret type, except that the EphemeralSecret::diffie_hellman method consumes and then wipes the secret key, and there are no serialization methods defined

To convert to Vec<u8> you can use StaticSecret which has a StaticSecret::to_bytes method and can be used multiple times as well as serialized.
So the final code would be something like
use num_bigint::{BigUint, RandBigInt};
use pyo3::prelude::*;
use pyo3::wrap_pyfunction;
use rand::rngs::OsRng;
use rand::Rng;
use rsa::pkcs1::{
    DecodeRsaPrivateKey, DecodeRsaPublicKey, EncodeRsaPrivateKey, EncodeRsaPublicKey,
};
use rsa::pkcs8::LineEnding;
use rsa::{Pkcs1v15Encrypt, RsaPrivateKey, RsaPublicKey};
use x25519_dalek::{PublicKey, StaticSecret};

// Diffie-Hellman
#[pyfunction]
fn generate_dh_key(p: &str, g: &str) -> PyResult<(String, String)> {
    let p = BigUint::parse_bytes(p.as_bytes(), 10)
        .ok_or_else(|| pyo3::exceptions::PyValueError::new_err("Invalid p"))?;
    let g = BigUint::parse_bytes(g.as_bytes(), 10)
        .ok_or_else(|| pyo3::exceptions::PyValueError::new_err("Invalid g"))?;

    let mut rng = OsRng;
    let private_key = rng.gen_biguint_below(&p);
    let public_key = g.modpow(&private_key, &p);

    Ok((private_key.to_str_radix(10), public_key.to_str_radix(10)))
}

#[pyfunction]
fn derive_dh_shared_key(private_key: &str, server_public_key: &str, p: &str) -> PyResult<String> {
    let p = BigUint::parse_bytes(p.as_bytes(), 10)
        .ok_or_else(|| pyo3::exceptions::PyValueError::new_err("Invalid p"))?;
    let private_key = BigUint::parse_bytes(private_key.as_bytes(), 10)
        .ok_or_else(|| pyo3::exceptions::PyValueError::new_err("Invalid private_key"))?;
    let server_public_key = BigUint::parse_bytes(server_public_key.as_bytes(), 10)
        .ok_or_else(|| pyo3::exceptions::PyValueError::new_err("Invalid server_public_key"))?;

    let shared_secret = server_public_key.modpow(&private_key, &p);
    Ok(shared_secret.to_str_radix(10))
}

// Elliptic Curve Diffie-Hellman
#[pyfunction]
fn generate_ecdh_key() -> PyResult<(Vec<u8>, Vec<u8>)> {
    let private_key = StaticSecret::random_from_rng(OsRng);
    let public_key = PublicKey::from(&private_key);

    Ok((
        private_key.to_bytes().to_vec(),
        public_key.as_bytes().to_vec(),
    ))
}

#[pyfunction]
fn derive_ecdh_shared_key(
    private_key_bytes: Vec<u8>,
    server_public_key_bytes: Vec<u8>,
) -> PyResult<Vec<u8>> {
    let private_key = StaticSecret::from(private_key_bytes.as_slice().try_into().unwrap());
    let server_public_key = PublicKey::from(server_public_key_bytes.as_slice().try_into().unwrap());

    let shared_secret = private_key.diffie_hellman(&server_public_key);
    Ok(shared_secret.as_bytes().to_vec())
}

// RSA Functions
#[pyfunction]
fn generate_rsa_key() -> (String, String) {
    let mut rng = OsRng;
    let bits = 2048;

    let private_key = RsaPrivateKey::new(&mut rng, bits).unwrap();
    let public_key = RsaPublicKey::from(&private_key);

    let private_pem = private_key.to_pkcs1_pem(LineEnding::LF).unwrap();
    let public_pem = public_key.to_pkcs1_pem(LineEnding::LF).unwrap();

    (private_pem.to_string(), public_pem)
}

#[pyfunction]
fn rsa_encrypt(public_key_pem: &str, message: &str) -> Vec<u8> {
    let public_key = RsaPublicKey::from_pkcs1_pem(public_key_pem).unwrap();
    let mut rng = OsRng;
    public_key
        .encrypt(&mut rng, Pkcs1v15Encrypt, message.as_bytes())
        .unwrap()
}

#[pyfunction]
fn rsa_decrypt(private_key_pem: &str, encrypted_data: Vec<u8>) -> String {
    let private_key = RsaPrivateKey::from_pkcs1_pem(private_key_pem).unwrap();
    let decrypted_data = private_key
        .decrypt(Pkcs1v15Encrypt, &encrypted_data)
        .unwrap();
    String::from_utf8(decrypted_data).unwrap()
}

// Swoosh NIKE key generation and exchange
#[pyfunction]
fn swoosh_generate_keys(parameters: (usize, usize, usize)) -> PyResult<(Vec<i8>, Vec<i8>)> {
    let (q, _d, n) = parameters;
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
    let a: Vec<i8> = (0..n * n).map(|_| rng.gen_range(0..q) as i8).collect();
    let s: Vec<i8> = (0..n).map(|_| rng.gen_range(-1..=1)).collect();
    let e: Vec<i8> = (0..n).map(|_| rng.gen_range(-1..=1)).collect();
    let public_key: Vec<i8> = a
        .chunks(n)
        .zip(&s)
        .map(|(row, &s)| (row.iter().sum::<i8>() + e[s as usize]) % q as i8)
        .collect();
    Ok((s, public_key))
}

#[pyfunction]
fn swoosh_derive_shared_key(
    private_key: Vec<i8>,
    public_key: Vec<i8>,
    q: usize,
) -> PyResult<Vec<i8>> {
    let shared_key: Vec<i8> = private_key
        .iter()
        .zip(&public_key)
        .map(|(&s, &p)| (s * p) % q as i8)
        .collect();
    Ok(shared_key)
}

#[pymodule]
fn shadow_crypt(m: &Bound<'_, PyModule>) -> PyResult<()> {
    m.add_function(wrap_pyfunction!(generate_dh_key, m)?)?;
    m.add_function(wrap_pyfunction!(derive_dh_shared_key, m)?)?;
    m.add_function(wrap_pyfunction!(generate_ecdh_key, m)?)?;
    m.add_function(wrap_pyfunction!(derive_ecdh_shared_key, m)?)?;
    m.add_function(wrap_pyfunction!(generate_rsa_key, m)?)?;
    m.add_function(wrap_pyfunction!(rsa_encrypt, m)?)?;
    m.add_function(wrap_pyfunction!(rsa_decrypt, m)?)?;
    m.add_function(wrap_pyfunction!(swoosh_generate_keys, m)?)?;
    m.add_function(wrap_pyfunction!(swoosh_derive_shared_key, m)?)?;
    Ok(())
}

Note: The Cargo.toml file needs to be modified as follows:
x25519_dalek = { version = "2.0.1", features = ["static_secrets"] }


So the StaticSecret would be a more suitable one to use? I dismissed it because whenever I tried to use it I got:   use x25519_dalek::{StaticSecret, PublicKey};
|                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
|                    |
|                    no StaticSecret in the root
|                    help: a similar name exists in the module: SharedSecret

It is feature gated behind static_secrets feature. Add it to the features in Cargo.toml
